# is_callable returns true but still cannot call function

Tags: php

I am on php 5.3.28 and I am trying to call a function like so:

```
...
$controller = new \Controller\Main();
$method = array($controller, $route . 'Action');

if (is_callable($method)) {
    return $method();
}
...
```

`is_callable` returns true, however the actual method call causes this error: `"Function name must be a string in ..."`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the array "[callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)" syntax, then you need to use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func).

```
if (is_callable($method)) {
    return call_user_func($method);
}
```

Comment: You can also do `$controller->{$route.'Action'}()` to call it :-P

Comment: There is one problem with is_callable - it returns true if class has a __call() method, so in general be careful with it. I was pulling my hair out trying to find out why my code tries to call methods which does not exist.

Comment: @JustAMartin: That's because, according to the class, that method *is* callable.  The `__call` method will handle it.  What you are probably looking for is [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php).